# Pypi package using setuptools: Upload Failed (400): Invalid file type in python2.7 or unknow type of file in python 3.5

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, twine

I try to make my python program into a command-like pypi package, so I can install the package using `pip install mypackage` and run my package with `mypackage` in the command windows. My python program is in [Github](https://github.com/Celthi/meltSubtitles). The Pypi page of my package is [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/meltsubtitles)

But I when I upload the package into [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/), I got an error "Upload failed (400): invalid file type" through python2.7, and "Upload failed (400): unknown type of file." in python3.5.

I have successfully uploaded a not-working version of my package once in windows on 04.17.2017. But today I fix my code and upload with "python setup.py bdist upload", and it prompts a password. After typing my password of Pypi, following error is showed:

`error: Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information`

After reading this [articles](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html), I thought maybe my password needs to escape. So I switch to my Linux to upload, but I got the following error:

`Upload failed (400): Unknown type of file.
error: Upload failed (400): Unknown type of file.`

But in dist folder, there is a new .tar.gz file. So I upload the new tar.gz file to Pypi using twine with `twine upload dist/newVersion`. On my pypi page, I could see the file has uploaded successfully. But when I try to install the new version with `pip install -U mypackage` or with an uninstallation and an installation. It appears no matter what I try, the olderst version is installed.

I can see in my Pypi page, only the newest version with a "NO" in the "Hide?" column, other with a "YES" in the hide column.

The changes I made to my package codes are mainly add a

```
package_data={
    'meltsubtitles': ['wordsRepo/en5000x.csv', 'wordsRepo/google-10000-english.txt'],
},
```

`version='1.5.0',`

and fix the error in `classifiers` and add an entry_points

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'meltsubtitles=meltsubtitles.main:main',
    ],
},
```

I have search the google with the error keywords "invalid file type" and look into some tutorial using `setuptools` to create command-like package, but still couldn't solve my problem.

Any help is aprriecated~!~